# Why I can't use Override annotations at Android?

Tags: java, android, annotations, compiler-errors, overriding

I'm developing an app to android but I can't use the Override annotations. It keeps saying that the method must override a superclass method, which does. I'm using Java 1.7 and Android API 8 (2.2). Using Eclipse.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Example

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.data.size();
}
```

But the compiler don't let me use @Override, saying its not a superclass method. I'm exetending BaseAdapter.

Comment: I promise you that if you try to construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) out of this, you'll find out what the error is yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using java 1.6 when building android projects. Java 1.7 isn't compatible with the current set of Android tools. Change your projects to use 1.6 and this problem should go away

In eclipse:
Right click project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> switch all references to 1.7 to 1.6

Comment: Actually this did the trick. The problem is that it solves one problem but add another. Now it is saying some references can't be found. I'm guessing this is an Eclipse bug, as I imported the project. I'm going to re-import the project and clean it to see if I can go along with 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use `@Override` annotation. If you get this error, it means you have a mistake in the prototype of the method, or you are not extending what you want to extend.

For example, on API level 8, the following will give you the error, as the method introduced in API 11:

```
@Override   
public void startActivities (Intent[] intents){

}
```